# Data Formatting in ios

Tags: iphone

I am doing a application which have a sharing note option to Ever-Note,i have done this,but my problem is ,the content of the note has to be static that means

```
 NSString * ENML = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">\n<en-note>"]autorelease];
```

this is the code i used to share a note to evernote,if i add note in

```
`NSString * ENML = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">\n<en-note> this is my note this is my note"]autorelease];`
```

it will share it to evernote
But my need is i have a textview which the user can create note dynamically with textview and i need something like that to do my need,

```
NSString * ENML = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">\n<en-note>textview.text"]autorelease];
```

but its not working.How can i do this?.please help me.
regards nipin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if your string is constant, you can just declare it as @"mystring";

In order to add a string inside another string, use stringWithFormat:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">\n<en-note>%@", textview.text];
```

The %@ in the string will be replaced with the value of textview.text. See "Formatting String Objects" in Apple's Developer Documentation for more info.

Comment: u r absolutly right,but i put this and shows an error that too many argument to callexpected1,have2

Comment: NSString * ENML= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">\n<en-note>%@", textview.text]; i put this but eroor that "bad formate"

Answer (score 0):

can't you do something like

```
NSString * ENML = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">\n<en-note> ";
ENML = [ENML stringByAppendingString:[textEntered text]];
ENML = [ENML stringByAppendingString:@"\">";
```

where textEntered is bound to a text field on the screen

Comment: what is textEntered?is this textview name?

Comment: You will no doubt have a textbox on the screen where the user types in the note.  I arbitarily called that textEntered